# Expected value of the Ito integral $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T 4W^4_t \,\text{d}W_t\right]$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I am confused on how to calculate the following $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T 4W^4_t \,\text{d}W_t\right]$$

Notes:

1. $W=(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion with the filtration $\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$.
2. From 1., the integrand is of course adapted to $\mathbb{F}$.
3. This integral is called Ito integral.

From the solution manual I have, it says since integrals w.r.t $W_t$ are martingales, so the value is $0$. How to see this fact?

Comment: See which fact? That integrals w.r.t. $W_t$ are martingales or that the expected value of a martingale is zero?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen the expected value is zero one. Thanks!

Comment: $E(M_{t_2}-M_{t_1}) = E(E(M_{t_2}-M_{t_1}\mid F_{t_1})=E(0)=0.$ And it's clear that the initial value of $M$ is zero here.

Comment: What textbook are you using?